# gcc x86-32 stack alignment and calling printf

Tags: gcc, x86, linker, gdb

To the best of my knowledge, x86-64 requires the stack to be 16-byte aligned before a call, while [gcc with `-m32` doesn't require this for main](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40325384/3163618).

I have the following testing code:

```
.data
intfmt:         .string "int: %d\n"
testint:        .int    20

.text
.globl main

main:
    mov     %esp, %ebp
    push    testint
    push    $intfmt
    call    printf
    mov     %ebp, %esp
    ret
```

Build with `as --32 test.S -o test.o && gcc -m32 test.o -o test`. I am aware that syscall write exists, but to my knowledge it cannot print ints and floats the way printf can.

After entering main, a 4 byte return address is on the stack. Then interpreting this code naively, the two push calls each put 4 bytes on the stack, so call needs another 4 byte value pushed to be aligned.

Here is the objdump of the binary generated by gas and gcc:

```
0000053d <main>:
 53d:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 53f:   ff 35 1d 20 00 00       pushl  0x201d
 545:   68 14 20 00 00          push   $0x2014
 54a:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   54b <main+0xe>
 54f:   89 ec                   mov    %ebp,%esp
 551:   c3                      ret    
 552:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 554:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 556:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 558:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 55a:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 55c:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 55e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

I am very confused about the push instructions generated.

1. If two 4 byte values are pushed, how is alignment achieved?
2. Why is 0x2014 pushed instead of 0x14? What is 0x201d?
3. What does `call 54b` even achieve? Output of `hd` matches `objdump`. Why is this different in gdb? Is this the dynamic linker?

```
B+>│0x5655553d <main>                       mov    %esp,%ebp                      │
   │0x5655553f <main+2>                     pushl  0x5655701d                     │
   │0x56555545 <main+8>                     push   $0x56557014                    │
   │0x5655554a <main+13>                    call   0xf7e222d0 <printf>            │
   │0x5655554f <main+18>                    mov    %ebp,%esp                      │
   │0x56555551 <main+20>                    ret
```

Resources on what goes on when a binary is actually executed are appreciated, since I don't know what's actually going on and the tutorials I've read don't cover it. I'm in the process of reading through [How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/).

Comment: `mov     %esp, %ebp` without saving / restoring the caller's `%ebp` is bad and could easily lead to a segfault after main returns.

Comment: Compile your C code with `gcc -O1 -fverbose-asm -S` to get assembler code. Read the relevant [x86 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) specification

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am hand writing assembly for learning purposes. I want to preserve as much of my original assembly as possible which I'm afraid `-O1` will get rid of.

Comment: Then remove `-O1`. Notice that the assembler is *generated* by `gcc` from some `foo.c` source code into `foo.s` after `gcc -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` (and you could add `-O1`). I did mention C code (not assembler) to understand what kind of assembler code `gcc` is generating

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm still not sure I understand. I am using `as` to create object file and `gcc` to create executable, no C source at all?

Comment: I was suggesting to compile some simple C code (like mentioned in the middle of your question) into assembler code and to look into the *generated* assembler. BTW you don't really need `gcc` on pure assembly (you could do direct [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) without using `printf`... and use `ld` to get an ELF executable). Read also [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)

Comment: Please provide some [MCVE] in your question. So show all the C code you got (if you have some), all the assembler code, and the building commands (probably with `as`, `ld`, maybe `gcc`). Give us enough information to reproduce your case on *our* computer. See also [OSDEV](https://www.osdev.org/). BTW, why do you need `printf` ?

Comment: The stack alignment requirement is an ABI *convention* tied to *your* [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). It is *not* required by the processor x86-64 ISA (you could even call functions *without* passing arguments on the stack, but that don't follow usual *conventions*)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have added my my build commands and the reasoning for using printf.

Comment: Have you carefully read all the resources I have linked to? They should provide an answer to your question. I still recommend compiling a tiny C program `foo.c` similar to your assembler program (with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O1 foo.c`) and looking into the generated assembler code `foo.s`. It should teach you useful things.

Comment: What you need to understand deeply is your ABI. I gave enough links and advices to understand it, but you do have several hours of reading

Comment: @qwr: The version of the i386 System V ABI used on Linux does require / guarantee 16-byte stack alignment before a `call`, just like the x86-64 System V ABI.  Could the phrasing in my answer you linked be improved to make that more clear?  `printf` is allowed to crash if it wants to if called with a misaligned stack like you're doing in this hand-written asm.  (But probably won't on systems where libc is compiled without SSE).

Comment: @PeterCordes I suppose my question #1 is really "why doesn't `printf` crash" if gcc doesn't do alignment

Comment: Because it doesn't do any 16-byte copies to / from the stack using `movaps` or `movdqa`.  Most functions in practice *don't* depend on the ABI-guaranteed alignment.  `scanf` does in recent x86-64 glibc, but it didn't used to.  [scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't change RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716).  Like I said, I don't think Ubuntu compiles their i386 glibc with SSE2 at all, and 3 pointers are only 12 bytes (not 24), so gcc probably wouldn't use a 16-byte copy anyway.

Comment: (Any function with a `double` on the stack will avoid cache-line splits for it, though, because they can give it 8-byte alignment relative to a known 16-byte alignment.  So certainly functions can take advantage of it, but will only crash from misalignment if they use SSE.  I guess you could imagine some kind of pointer-alignment calculation with AND that assumes alignment to start with, and would produce wrong behaviour with misalignment...)

Comment: @PeterCordes ok can you post this as an answer? I have never heard of when functions do and don't care about alignment and I have never written SSE. Of course it is good to follow the ABI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The i386 System V ABI *does* guarantee / require 16 byte stack alignment before a `call`, like I said at the top of my answer that you linked.  (Unless you're calling a private helper function, in which case you can make up your own rules for alignment, arg-passing, and which registers are clobbered for that function.)

**Functions are *allowed* to crash or misbehave if you violate this ABI requirement, but are not required to.**  e.g. `scanf` in x86-64 Ubuntu glibc (as compiled by recent gcc) only recently started doing that:  [scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't change RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716)

Functions can depend on stack alignment for performance (to align a `double` or array of `double`s to avoid cache-line splits when accessing them).

Usually the only case where a function depends on stack alignment for *correctness* is when compiled to use SSE/SSE2, so it can use 16-byte alignment-required loads/stores to copy a struct or array (`movaps` or `movdqa`), or to actually auto-vectorize a loop over a local array.

I think Ubuntu doesn't compile their 32-bit libraries with SSE (except functions like `memcpy` that use runtime dispatching), so they can still work on ancient CPUs like Pentium II.  Multiarch libraries on an x86-64 system should assume SSE2, but with 4-byte pointers it's less likely that 32-bit functions would have 16 byte structs to copy.

Anyway, whatever the reason, obviously `printf` in your 32-bit build of glibc doesn't actually depend on 16-byte stack alignment for correctness, so it doesn't fault even when you misalign the stack.

---

> Why is 0x2014 pushed instead of 0x14? What is 0x201d?

`0x14` (decimal 20) is the value in memory at that location.  It will be loaded at runtime, because you used `push r/m32`, not `push $20` (or an assemble time constant like `.equ testint, 20` or `testint = 20`).

**You used `gcc -m32` to make a PIE (Position Independent Executable), which is relocated at runtime**, because that's the default on Ubuntu's gcc.

`0x2014` is the offset relative to the start of the file.  If you disassemble at runtime after running the program, you'll see a real address.

Same for `call 54b`.  It's presuambly a call to the PLT (which is near the start of the file / text segment, hence the low address).

If you disassembled with `objdump -drwC`, you'd see symbol relocation info.  (I like `-Mintel` as well, but beware it's MASM-like, not NASM).

You can link with `gcc -m32 -no-pie` to make classic position-*dependent* executables.  I'd definitely recommend that especially for 32-bit code, and especially if you're compiling C, use `gcc -m32 -no-pie -fno-pie` to get non-PIE code-gen as well as linking into a non-PIE executable.  (see [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) for more about PIEs.)

Comment: And is 0x2014 and 0x201d values that are replaced during dynamic linking? I am using default Ubuntu 18.04 and whatever `printf` came with that.

Comment: @qwr: yes, you made a PIE executable because that's the gcc default on recent Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your reference to PIE, that is what I was looking for.